# Unable to open excel file in clojure - only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor

Tags: java, excel, clojure, zip, apache-poi

I am trying to open and parse an excel file with [this library](https://github.com/mjul/docjure), however, I am getting the following error:

```
clj-spelling-list-parser.core> (spreadsheet/load-workbook "list20150410.xlsx")
clojure.core/eval                           
core.clj: 3081
clj-spelling-list-parser.core/eval26754 form-init5197475672653279465.clj:  112
dk.ative.docjure.spreadsheet/eval4923/fn spreadsheet.clj:   79
dk.ative.docjure.spreadsheet/load-workbook-from-file spreadsheet.clj:   64
dk.ative.docjure.spreadsheet/load-workbook-from-stream spreadsheet.clj:   58
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create WorkbookFactory.java:   87
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open OPCPackage.java:  272
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>  ZipPackage.java:   88
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init> ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:   51
java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry ZipInputStream.java:  122
java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC ZipInputStream.java:  310
java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share a bit of code how you call WorkbookFactory, it seems either the file that you pass is corrupted or you try to parse an XLS files as XLSX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed by opening the file in question in excel and saving it again. Seems like excel automatically fixes any errors it finds.